# Best way to represent set of string values in DB and UI

Tags: java, database-design, relational-database

I'm looking for opinions so I guess this is a 'which is better' question. I have a webapp build in Javascript/jQuery and struts that uses Hibernate to access data in a relational DB (MySQL). When an object/database field has a limited set of strings for values, is it better to use the full string in the object/DB or a 'code' for that string, like a single CHAR instead of the entire string?

```
class User {
    int    id;
    String userName;
    String type;        // Values of 'Administrator', 'Regular'
OR
    char   type         // Values of 'A', 'R'
OR 
    char   type         // Values of 'A', 'R'
    String typeString;  // Can be returned on the fly based on 'type' or by DB in SQL CASE statement
}
```

If the database has the full text string, then its easy coding all the way around, but its wasting the space (in the DB, data transfer) on something that only has a few values.

If the database has just a 'code' then when presenting this field to a user ( like in a grid of existing users, or a dropdown selection list when creating a new user ) the char value must be converted to the full string. Then the question is where should that conversion be done? It could be at the DB level where Hibernate can fill in the full string value from a CASE statement. This saves DB space, but not in data transfer or memory. It could be at the object level where its done in the getter/setter for the 'type' field. Or it could be all the way in the GUI where Javascript converts the 'char' to the appropriate string for the user to see.

Also... if either method is OK to use, what might influence the choice you make? The number of different values? The max length of the strings? How many rows are expected in the table?

I'm sure every DB/programmer has come across this situation many times and probably has a preference.

Comment: The traditional way is to have a code and a lookup table that maps code to string value. It's important not to use the full strings as you may inadvertantly insert bad strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to do the conversion from the typecode to type (and vice versa) as close to database interaction as possible - in this case Hibernate. This is because your application logic would become more readable and intuitive if it uses the explicit types.

In my opinion- `if(BMW.equals(carTypeCode)) {}` is lot more readable than `if("X".equals(carTypeCode)) {}`.

I am not very familiar with Hibernate, but it would be awesome if you could leverage Hibernate for the mapping of String to DB representation and vice versa (maybe using CASE as you mentioned). Personally, I would probably have modeled these Strings as enums and used something like [Hibernate Enum Type mapping](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-enum-type-mapping-example). Also, you should think about making these type codes a little bit readable by making them at least few chars because these may come in handy when you are debugging some issue by looking at DB dump and you don't have to consult your type-code to type conversion chart.

I don't think performance wise either would not impact much in the average case.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a fixed set of user types like `Admin` and `Regular`, I think it will easier to use a static hashmap in your code and just store `A` and `R` in your code. Something like:

```
static HashMap<Character,String> userRoles = new HashMap<>();

static{
       userRoles.put("A","Admin");
       userRoles.put("R", "Regular");
}
```

When ever you get result from DB, you can just do `userRoles.get(type)` to check the actual type. This saves space and also it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the full name in the database alongside an associated short code or ID in some kind of lookup table. Use the shortcode/ID as the primary key for the lookup table, and as a foreign key from other tables. If someone needs to investigate the database layer, or someone needs to use the database for reporting, data warehousing, or analytics this will simplify things greatly.

It's commonly seen as bad practice to name variables, database tables, database columns, functions, etc. with unclear names or abbreviations that not everyone will understand - short codes like this should be seen the same way.